# Solaar and onboard are showing twice in the tray-bar after upgrading to Debian 12

Tags: debian, kde, plasma, tray

After upgrading Debian11/KDE to Debian 12, `Solaar` (for bluetooth input devices) and `onboard` (for a virtual touchscreen keyboard) is showing twice in the tray-bar. I checked with the process manager and there only is one process for each of those.

Why are they showing twice and how to prevent that?

No other are shown twice there. The context menu can be shown for both tray icons of Solaar. The second tray-icon for onboard looks slightly different than the other. When I click on the latter only a context menu is shown, when I click on the first they onboard keyboard is shown so these are definitely different. It may have to do with Plasma tray icon settings files (which should not be screwed up by updating).

The four icons look like this in the tray: [image]

I used X11 before and after the upgrade. When I switch to Wayland, the Onboard keyboard does show after login but, unlike with X11, it does not show in the tray (Solaar is in the tray with one icon) once I close that keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this issue in Debian 12 (MX-Linux 23). Only some programs will appear twice. And they appear twice only during auto-start, but if you kill the program and explicitly relaunch it, it only appears once in the system tray.

In general, it is more difficult to read other people's code than writing your own. So incompetent novice programmers always tend to deprecate old code and rewrite their own, but they neglect certain key issues, that is why after every upgrade, you always see some new bugs here and there. That is very common. The trick is to stick to old version for 1-2 years before upgrading to new release.